# sp_getProcedureColumns Column Type

Tags: advantage-database-server

How do I find out what the value of the COLUMN_TYPE returned from sp_getProcedureColumns?
The value returned is an shortInt.

There is nothing in the documentation for this system procedure.

Thanks,

Howard

Answer (score 1):

It is equivalent to the ODBC function [SQLProcedureColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711701(VS.85).aspx)

Type = 1: Input

Type = 3: Result column, i.e. column in output cursor.

Those are the only two types that should be returned.